# Problem displaying Bi directional characters in wpf c# application windows7

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

I have an WPF c# application which pulls data from an API.

The expected string is `⁦@narendramodi’s⁩`

But in windows 7 machine , i am getting as 
[image]

In windows 10 machine i am getting the result as expected

I copied the text and pasted in notepad(windows 10) , and found the text had something like this

[image]

As i dig deeper, i found this is a bidirectional text identifier. 
[Wiki link for bi directional text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text#Unicode_support)

My query is how to i resolve this issue in windows 7.

The font that i use in the application is

> ariel ms Unicode

Comment: How do you create the strings? Do get them from the API? It looks like they contain invisible control characters. Can you configure the API to disable  bidirectional script support? Otherwise you have to trim leading and trailing characters (U+2066 and U+2069 )

Comment: The string if from the API. I don't think that we can configure the API to disable it. I can try removing the characters and see if it helps.